# Ignored tags - better UX suggestion

Tags: feature-request, design, ignored-tags

I just noticed that, when we are ignoring a few tags, yes, I know we make it less opaque. But, that also makes the border to be less opaque. Consider the below picture:

[image: preview]

The two borders are in different opacity. Can we just reduce only the opacity of the contents, instead of the borders? Just thought of asking this, and if there's any reason behind having it this way, then I am happy.

<sup>ps: Even now I am happy!</sup>